# Calendar getInstance get and set not working

Tags: android, get, calendar, set

I want to change android calendar time.
this is my code :

```
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
```

... other codes and methods

```
        System.out.println("h : " + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    System.out.println("m :" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    System.out.println("s :" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

But no change occurred

get  method return me default emulation time

can eny one help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    System.out.println("h : " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    System.out.println("m :" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    System.out.println("s :" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Comment: I need to use calendar instance later i another calendar.

Comment: you can not change defult time of android pogramically so you have to change it for instance

Comment: yes so new instanse always return your emulated time thats y u have to use setinstace for